# Strange <user-permission> error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

For some reason I get a nasty error when adding an `user-permission` for `CALL_PHONE` and `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

```
Error:(16) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
```

It gives an error at this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE " />
```

When removing the space after between the PHONE and " it still gives me the error.

I've tried cleaning, Rebuilding and restarting.
A lost of lines are red..

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.daxrahusen.navigationdrawervideotutorial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE " />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.daxrahusen.navigationdrawervideotutorial.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="...Parse..." />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="...Parse..." />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="...Google..." />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.daxrahusen.navigationdrawervideotutorial.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.daxrahusen.navigationdrawervideotutorial.login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.EnableWalletOptimizationReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.ENABLE_WALLET_OPTIMIZATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Make sure that you are removing the space in your own manifest. Sometimes, Android Studio will show you an error in the *generated* manifest, the one that combines entries from your manifest, library manifests, `build.gradle`, etc.

Comment: quick answer: have you tried removing the space after the permission? so the new permission would be: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: If tried removing the whitespace, no effect.
@CommonsWare, what do you mean with generated maniftest, sometimes is see a new tap open with another `AndroidManifest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file that goes into your APK is not the `AndroidManifest.xml` that you write. Instead, through what is known as the manifest merger process, an `AndroidManifest.xml` file is generated that contains material from:

- All of your manifests that you wrote, across your different sourcesets (e.g., `src/main/`, `src/debug/`, `src/release`)
- All of the manifests contributed by library modules or AARs that you pull from artifact repositories
- Settings in `build.gradle`, such as `minSdkVersion`

This generated manifest is saved in `build/intermediates/manifests/...`, where the `...` depends a bit on what sort of build you are doing (e.g., `debug` versus `release`).

Sometimes, when there is a bug in your manifest, the problem is not caught until after the manifest merger has been done. Android Studio then opens up a tab showing you the generated manifest, pointing out the problem. Editing this manifest is pointless, as it gets regenerated on every build. Instead, you need to go to whatever manifest contains the flawed XML and fix that manifest.

"It keeps setting the whitespace back" suggests that you are editing the generated manifest, not your original one.

Answer (score 3):

you should delete the whitespace character at the end of it

change

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE " />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: what do you mean it keeps setting it back?!

Comment: @SwingerDinger: This definitely sounds like you are editing the generated manifest, not the manifest that has the original `<uses-permission>` element.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the space after the CALL_PHONE in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE " />
```

make it like :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Make sure that you are doing this in app manifest, not in the generated manifest, generated manifest is not editable.